# Python failure on mod.bind()

Tags: python, mxnet

### Description

Index type must be set for one_hot operator, but I do not find where or how to set it.

### Environment info

----------Python Info----------

Version      : 3.6.5

Compiler     : GCC 7.2.0

Build        : ('default', 'Apr 29 2018 16:14:56')

Arch         : ('64bit', '')

------------Pip Info-----------

Version      : 10.0.1

Directory    : /home/augustinas/anaconda3/envs/mxnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip

----------MXNet Info-----------

Version      : 1.3.0

Directory    : /home/augustinas/anaconda3/envs/mxnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet

Commit Hash   : 247d57944f7a989d8f445856769e704b83765828

----------System Info----------

Platform     : Linux-4.13.0-43-generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid

system       : Linux

node         : augustinasNT

release      : 4.13.0-43-generic

version      : #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 17 12:56:46 UTC 2018

### Error Message:

RuntimeError: simple_bind error. Arguments:

data: (1, 3, 112, 112)

Error in operator one_hot0: [19:29:50] src/operator/tensor/./indexing_op.h:1002: Check failed: (*in_attrs)[0] != -1 (-1 vs. -1) Index type must be set for one_hot operator

Stack trace returned 10 entries:

[bt] (0) /home/augustinas/anaconda3/envs/mxnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/libmxnet.so(+0x1d7c2a) [0x7fd3b2363c2a]

[bt] (1) /home/augustinas/anaconda3/envs/mxnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/libmxnet.so(+0x1d8261) [0x7fd3b2364261]

[bt] (2) /home/augustinas/anaconda3/envs/mxnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/libmxnet.so(+0x211641f) [0x7fd3b42a241f]

[bt] (3) /home/augustinas/anaconda3/envs/mxnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/libmxnet.so(+0x2672116) [0x7fd3b47fe116]

[bt] (4) /home/augustinas/anaconda3/envs/mxnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/libmxnet.so(+0x267b971) [0x7fd3b4807971]

[bt] (5) /home/augustinas/anaconda3/envs/mxnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/libmxnet.so(+0x267c3ca) [0x7fd3b48083ca]

[bt] (6) /home/augustinas/anaconda3/envs/mxnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/libmxnet.so(+0x266ca22) [0x7fd3b47f8a22]

[bt] (7) /home/augustinas/anaconda3/envs/mxnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/libmxnet.so(+0x266d434) [0x7fd3b47f9434]

[bt] (8) /home/augustinas/anaconda3/envs/mxnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/libmxnet.so(MXExecutorSimpleBind+0x2378) [0x7fd3b47574a8]

[bt] (9) /home/augustinas/anaconda3/envs/mxnet/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/../../libffi.so.6(ffi_call_unix64+0x4c) [0x7fd3cf795ec0]

Comment: Could you provide a code sample that reproduces this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looking at the documentation of `one_hot`, you need to provide two arguments, `indices` and `depth` which are both required. Similar arguments are required for `mx.symbol.one_hot` and `mx.ndarray.one_hot`, but `indices` would be of type Symbol and NDArray respectively.

1) `indices` (of type NDArray/Symbol): array of locations where to set on_value

2) `depth` (of type int): depth of the one hot dimension (i.e. number of classes)

An example of this looks like:

```
one_hot([1,0,2,0], 3) = [[ 0.  1.  0.]
                         [ 1.  0.  0.]
                         [ 0.  0.  1.]
                         [ 1.  0.  0.]]
```